# Libgdx FreeTypeFont Label text with ortographic camera

Tags: android, libgdx, label, scene2d

I have a Stage that has a Viewport with an Ortographic Camera with dimensions of (Height, 10) (I calculate the Height corresponding to the 10 width depending on the screen)

Im trying to make a label but when i run the game, it shows some big pixels and i suppose it has to do with the ortographic camera and the font size (Which is 30, for example). I tried reducing the font size but it does not fix the problem, ill attach some images so you can see what is going on.

The problem has to do with the viewport as i tested the same label in another Stage that didnt have that viewport and it drew the label perfectly.
How can i add a label to my stage that has an ortographic camera?

[image: OrtoStage]

[image: NotOrto Stage]

Comment: wow those are some large images...

Comment: Sorry, thats how they came out of Android Studio Screenshot function :(

Comment: U sure you 're setting the dimensions properly? a viewport with a dimension of 10 means it only has 10 pixels to show. Your first sample image looks like it's showing 6 pixels worth of one of your letters, with 4 blank pixels to the left. The pixels are "big" because you're telling the viewport to only show 10 of them?

Comment: I thought one of the useful things of the Ortographic Camera was to set sort of your own dimentions, thats why i define the width as 10, refering to 10 units, then based on that i calculate the height. But then as the font parameter is based on pixels (i think) then it looks terrible

Comment: I think you want to use some Pixel per meter technique for your game. In my experience, you should make an another stage to display your ui. If you really want to use PPM camera, try use `project` and `unproject` to observe what position in screen space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As you said, im doing separate stages for the UI, so it works now!